# How to filter by Array in Vapor 4?

Tags: vapor

I can do a filter in Vapor 4 like this

```swift
Category.query(on: req.db)
   .filter(\.$description ~~ searchTags)
```

`description` here is a String. And it will match description to any of the strings in the `searchTags` array.

But what if description was also an array?  Is there a way to match all the values in descriptionArray to the searchTags array?

Answer (score 1):

If description was an array, then it should be made into an array of child objects, this way you can search for using a simple filter on description and parent id.